# Unix converting time format to integer value

Tags: bash, unix

I have the following text file.

```
Account1,2h 01m 00s
Account2,4h 25m 23s
Account3,5h 43m 59s
```

I wish to add the values of hours, minutes and seconds in order to total them to their respective minute totals.

```
Account1 minute total = 121
Account2 minute total = 265
Account3 minute total = 343
```

I have the following bash file

```
cat data.txt | cut -f2 -d','
```

This isolates the time values; however, from here I don't know what steps I would take to isolate the time, convert it to integers and then convert it to minutes. I have tried using a PARAM but to no avail.

Comment: Show what you've tried — what you mean by "using a PARAM".

Comment: This could be trivially broken down into two separate problems, each of which is already answered on this site. (1) How do I extract values with a regex in bash? (2) How do I multiply numbers from bash? -- for (1), look for answers using `BASH_REMATCH`

Comment: Are you allowed to use `awk`?  Do you know how to use `awk`?

Comment: Your `cut` command throws away the account information, so you're going to have to do something different from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `awk` is an option, you can try this

```
awk -F"[, ]" '{h=60; m=1; s=0.01666667}{split($2,a,/h/); split($3,b,/m/); split($4,c,/s/); print$1, "minute total = " int(a[1] * h + b[1] * m + c[1] * s)}' input_file
```

```
$ cat awk.script

BEGIN {
  FS=",| "
} {
  h=60
  m=1
  s=0.01666667
}{
  split($2,a,/h/)
  split($3,b,/m/)
  split($4,c,/s/)
  print $1, "minute total = " int(a[1] * h + b[1] * m + c[1] * s)
}
```

**Output**

```
awk -f awk.script input_file
Account1 minute total = 121
Account2 minute total = 265
Account3 minute total = 343
```